# ROUND second argument only takes constant + hive

Tags: hive, arguments, constants, rounding

The following:

```
hive> create table t1 (val double, digit int);
hive> insert into t1 values(10,2);
hive> insert into t1 values(156660,3);
hive> insert into t1 values(8765450,4);
hive> select round(val, digit) from round_test;
```

Gives this error:

> FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10014]: Line 1:7 Wrong arguments
>   'digit': ROUND second argument only takes constant

Its working fine in impala.

Could somebody help me please point out where the error is coming from?

Comment: Please add some textual description.

Comment: do you want to round off value for both val, digit? also what is  round_test table? you added values in table t1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says that the secund argument of ROUND must be a costant. i.e. with hive you can't use a column as secund argument for your ROUND function. If you need to do that I'd suggest you to create you UDF.

Answer (score 1):

```
    BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal(value);
    BigDecimal roundOff = a.setScale(places, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN);
    return roundOff.doubleValue();
```

Thanks Mark for your quick response.

I've already used UDF to solve this issue. As this is a known issue HIVE-4523. Thought some patch has already applied.